# Jekyll - link to posts from pages

Tags: jekyll

A very basic question.

I can not find out how to refer or cite a post in a page.

If this is my post

```
---
layout: post
title:  "Serve Jekyll Websites with servr and knitr"
categories: [jekyll, rstats]
tags: [knitr, servr, httpuv, websocket]
---

The R package [**servr**](https://github.com/yihui/servr) can be used to set up an HTTP server to serve files under a directory.
```

How I am suppose to cite it in my `page`

```
---
layout: page
title: About
permalink: /about/
---

You can find out more info in this post
```

Could you help me out ?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can do this 2 ways:

1. Copy-pasting the link generated for your post as a link to it.

   `[Check Out My Post!](www.example.com/posts/2015-10-1-name-of-post/)`

   This definitely works, but will break/fail when you decide to change link style, or have another permalink, or when you change file names.
2. The **smarter** way: Jekyll's built in `post_url`

   Jekyll has a built in function that allows you to internally link or cite back to posts on your website. [Here is the documentation](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/templates/#post-url) for it, but I will explain the syntax and usage as well.

   Assuming you want to link to a Jekyll post with the filename of `2015-07-17-jekyll-servr-tutorial.md` which is located in the `_posts` folder, the syntax for this would be:

   - `{% post_url 2015-07-17-jekyll-servr-tutorial %}`
   - `{% post_url /tutorials/2015-07-17-jekyll-servr-tutorial %}` if you have your posts organized in a subdirectory called `tutorials`
   - `The R Package [servr]({% post_url 2015-07-17-jekyll-servr-tutorial %})` if you want to make hyperlinks.

There is **no need** to include the file extension name when using this liquid tag function.

[Here](http://brm.io/jekyll-post-links/) is additional information and a tutorial on how to use Jekyll post-links that you might find useful as well.